# Can't loop array after grouping with .reduce

Tags: javascript, loops

I've got the following `meetings` object :

```
[
    {
        "id": 19,
        "duration": 1.75,
        "Employee": {
            "name": "Jeanne",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "duration": 1.00,
        "Employee": {
            "name": "Louis",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "duration": 1.00,
        "Employee": {
            "name": "Jeanne",
        }
    }

]
```

I want to group it by Employee.name. Using `reduce()` here is what I come up with :

```
meetings.reduce(function (r, a) {
            r[a.Employee.name] = r[a.Employee.name] || [];
            r[a.Employee.name].push(a);
            return r;
}
```

The resulting object is the following :

```
{
    "Jeanne": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "duration": 1.75,
            "Employee": {
                "name": "Jeanne"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "duration": 1.00,
            "Employee": {
                "name": "Jeanne"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Louis": [
        {
            "id": 20,
            "duration": 1.00,
            "Employee": {
                "name": "Louis"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I try to `map()` or `forEach()` i cannot get the value of the element :

```
Array.from(thisMeeting).forEach(element => console.log(element)); 
return `undefined`;
```

Comment: `forEach` is an array function, your reduce is creating an object.  You could maybe use `Object.entries(thisMetting).forEach(([key, value]) => `  to do what your after.

Comment: There is no `meetings.data` in what you posted.

Comment: If you want to iterate over an object, then you'll probably appreciate [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: @Pointy indeed, I corrected the question

Answer (score 1):

Array.from-ming an Object will result in an empty array.
You'll have to iterate over the objects keys with `Object.entries(thisMeeting).forEach…` and grab the values inside that.